# EF Core SQL Coordinate type

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have Azure sql database with a table of objects. One of the columns is going to hold a coordinate (longitude and latitude) so I assume it is going to be the [point type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017).

What C# Type do I use to represent this type and how do I show it in my model?

Answer (score 0):

EF Core added [Spatial data support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) in EF Core 2.2 through the [NetTopolobySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) library. You need to add the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite) package to your project.

Points are represented by the [Point](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_geometries_1_1_point.html) class, preferably accessed through the [IPoint interface](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/interface_geo_a_p_i_1_1_geometries_1_1_i_point.html). As the docs explain, the preferred way to create instances is through [factory methods](https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/interface_geo_a_p_i_1_1_geometries_1_1_i_geometry_factory.html):

```
var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
IPoint currentLocation = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(-122.121512, 47.6739882);
```

Comment: When using the `IPoint` in the model and then creating a migration (with ef core tools) I get `The property 'Object.Location' is of an interface type ('IPoint'). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property
by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the NotMappedAttribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'`. What should I do?